# Can I configure Unity to automatically return a fake for interfaces that are not registered?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, unity-container

I'm a bit tired of manually registering fake dependencies in my unit tests... I'm wondering if there is a way to configure Unity in such a way that, if there is no registered implementation for a given type, it automatically creates a fake using FakeItEasy or some other mocking framework.

So instead of writing this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

var fooProvider = A.Fake<IFooProvider>();
container.RegisterInstance(fooProvider);
var barService = A.Fake<IBarService>();
container.RegisterInstance(barService);
var bazManager = A.Fake<IBazManager>();
container.RegisterInstance(bazManager);

var sut = container.Resolve<SystemUnderTest>();
```

I could just write something like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AutoFake();
var sut = container.Resolve<SystemUnderTest>();
```

Is it possible? I was looking for some kind of callback that would be called when Unity tries to resolve a type, but I couldn't find anything. There seems to be plenty of extensibility points, with extensions, strategies, policies, call handlers and so forth, but I don't have a clue where to start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I managed to do it, using [AutoMocking](https://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking) (thanks to Sam Holder for the link) as an example to create a Unity extension. The code is relatively simple:

```
public class AutoFakeExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Strategies.AddNew<AutoFakeBuilderStrategy>(UnityBuildStage.PreCreation);
    }

    private class AutoFakeBuilderStrategy : BuilderStrategy
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo _fakeGenericDefinition;

        static AutoFakeBuilderStrategy()
        {
            _fakeGenericDefinition = typeof(A).GetMethod("Fake", Type.EmptyTypes);
        }

        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            if (context.Existing == null)
            {
                var type = context.BuildKey.Type;
                if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
                {
                    var fakeMethod = _fakeGenericDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(type);
                    var fake = fakeMethod.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
                    context.PersistentPolicies.Set<ILifetimePolicy>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), context.BuildKey);
                    context.Existing = fake;
                    context.BuildComplete = true;
                }
            }
            base.PreBuildUp(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<AutoFakeExtension>();

// The IFoo dependency is provided automatically using FakeItEasy
var test = container.Resolve<Test>();

public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Test
{
    public Test(IFoo foo)
    {
    }
}
```

This implementation is probably not suitable for all use cases, but it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Unity doesn't have this out of the box, but there is a project called [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture) that aims to provide what you want. I'm not certain there is support for Unity out of the box, but as I understand it is possible to plug in your own containers.

[This project](https://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking) also does something similar, but again I don't think it supports unity out of the box

Comment: Yes, I know about AutoFixture, but at first glance it didn't seem to do what I wanted. Maybe I need to dig a bit deeper... The other project you linked is also interesting, but it seems to use its own IoC container, which isn't an option for me (I use property injection in many places, so I'm tied to Unity because of the `[Dependency]` attribute)

Comment: Actually, the Automocking project does use Unity internally; I'm not sure I'll be able to use it directly, but at least I can find some ideas on how to do what I want. Thanks for the link.

Comment: AutoFixture should do what you want, @ThomasLevesque, if you use the [AutoFakeItEasy package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy).
Also, you may want to try FakeItEasy's default fixture intializers (the `UnderTest` and `Fake` attributes–check them out in the code).

Comment: @BlairConrad, you're right, I didn't realize it would be so easy. I thought it wouldn't pick up the `[Dependency]` attribute on the properties, but apparently it doesn't care about attributes, it just sets public properties.